# First time with MVC

Tags: model-view-controller

Im new to MVC and I would like to ask about routing and controllers.

I have a controller called an LprController

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

and I have a view called ScanPage

```
@model FCoai.FCWCF.PCSResult

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ScanPage";
}

<h2>ScanPage</h2>
```

and here's my routeconfig

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

I'm trying to directly display the scanpage screen instead of the regular MVC about page but I'm having no success. I'm using a service reference that's why I have no model class, please give me some tips on how to do response.redirects like how I'm used to doing with regular asp web programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display the scan page as a default page in your web app, you need to do three things:

1. Add the following action to your controller "it should match the view name":

   ```
   public ActionResult ScanPage()
   {
        return View();
   }
   ```
2. Make sure your `scanpage.chtml` is placed in the following path `"views/Lpr/scanpage.cshtml"`. Note that `Lpr` in the path is the name of your controller "without the `Controller` suffix".
3. Make your page the default page in the following routing line:
   So, you need to change this:

   ```
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
   ```

   into this:

   ```
   defaults: new { controller = "Lpr", action = "ScanPage", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
   ```

That's it. Hoping this would help you.

Comment: Thanks this helped me with displaying the page by putting ScanPage() in front of ActionResult. But how do I redirect between pages?

Comment: There are two ways of redirection: As a link inside a view or from an ActionResult to another.